# Do not see Access Key on Azure for Power Bi Workspace

Tags: azure, powerbi, workspace, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to create a PowerBi Embedded application on Azure Portal. I successfully created one but I am not able to see the Access Key in the list of options.

I followed the above documentation.[link](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-developer-register-app/)

[image]

I have a Visual Studio Enterprise – MPN subscription. Hope that wasn't the reason.

Also I couldn't find the settings icon also. 
Help is appreciated .Thanks

Comment: I don't understand about the access key you're referencing.  I created a Power BI embedded resource and mine looks exactly like yours. To access it, you need to get an Azure AD token, representing a user login.  They have samples for that: https://github.com/guyinacube/PowerBI-Developer-Samples

Answer (score -1):

Why have you created a "Power BI Embedded"-service in Azure? I dont see anything mentioning that in the guide to supplied.

"Power BI Embedded" in azure is deprecated, instead you should register an app accouring to the **Register with the Azure portal**-step:

> In the left-hand navigation pane, choose More Services, select App
>   Registrations under Security + Identity and select New application
>   registration.

Comment: Power BI capacity in Azure is a new feature release in October '17. 
This a new feature that tries to remove confusion around licensing and make it more affordable to embed content for non-powerbi users.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/power-bi-embedded/create-capacity